# How can I calculate the number of "ATC" in a dna sequence in r

Tags: r

I have a fasta file containing a dna sequence. I want to calculate the number of times "ATC" occurs in my sequence.

For example, mydna <- "ATCGCGCATCGATCGC"

I want my output to be 3 as "ATC" occurs only twice in mydna

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One `base R` option could be:

```
length(grepRaw("ATC", x, all = TRUE, fixed = TRUE))

[1] 3
```

Comment: Or using `str_count` `str_count(mydna, "ATC")`

Answer (score 0):

Another base R solution is using `gregexpr()`

```
lengths(gregexpr("ATC",mydna))
```

such that

```
> lengths(gregexpr("ATC",mydna))
[1] 3
```